# How to target the data-role contain

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have three pages. Each has a `data-role="content"` attribute.

How do I target parts of a page programmatically? (e.g. `data-role = "firstPage"` --> only the footer from this page or the content attribute).

I'm using jQuery Mobile 1.3.0

Comment: I have updated my answer with a working example. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easy:

```
$('[data-role="firstPage"]')
```

jQuery Reference:

> ### [Attribute Equals Selector [name=”value”]](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)
>
> Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value exactly equal to a certain value.

Comment: Hey, BLSully, thanks for the prompt answer. That would be the case if I wanted to select the "firstPage" data-role, which would be the first page. But what if I want to target the first-page's contain data-role ?

Comment: @Nactus you would do what BLSully has, but add `.find("theelementiwant")`

Comment: Hey Kevin, thanks for your answer. So, it would be something like this: $('[data-role="#firstPage"]').find('content') ... and then what I wanted it to do, like .click(function(){}), right ?

Comment: @Nactus: sorry was AFK when you asked, but glad to see KevinB helped you get sorted out

Answer (score 2):

Each page should have an ID.

HTML

```
<div data-role="page id="page1"></div>
```

Page 1 with ID `page1`

```
$('[data-role="page"]#page1')
```

Page 2 with ID `page2`

```
$('[data-role="page"]#page2')
```

Page 3 with ID `page3`

```
$('[data-role="page"]#page3')
```

I have included some [examples here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Palestinian/a6vQn/).

Answer (score 1):

It would be the best to give each part an unique id and then to target them with a jQuery Selector.

Your HTML:

```
<div id="home-page"></div>
```

Your JS:

```
$("#home-page").html('Test!');
```

Your Result:

```
<div id="home-page">Test!</div>
```

Comment: Reflic, thanks for your answer. What if I only want to  target the content attribute of "home-page"? Thanks. It is my understanding that for pages (in jQuery) the three elements (header, content, and footer) should always stay with these names).